# Dynamically creating and iterating through class attributes/properties in a base class

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, attributes

I have two classes which are very similar. In fact, the only difference between the two classes is that one of the classes has an extra field.

In order to keep the code DRY, I want the two classes to inherit from a base class, but I'm not sure how to deal with the additional field attribute.

A solution could be to iterate through the attributes of the class, and implement that in a base class. The following pseudocode illustrates this:

```
class WidgetBase():
    __base_required_field_names = ('a','b','c')

    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.__encountered_names = []

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            # ensure name not previously encountered, else raise error
            # create attribute and assign value
            pass

        # if not all required base fields not provided raise error


    def update(self, **kwargs):
        #  if unknown field raise error, else update field
        pass

    def write_to_file(self):
        # write attributes to CSV file
        pass


class Widget(BaseWidget):
    pass


class AdvancedWidget(BaseWidget):
    pass


# Example Usage

from datetime import datetime
import csv

widget = Widget('foo',a=1729,b=None,c=datetime.now())
widget.update(a=22,b='Babylonia')
widget.write_to_file()

awe = AdvancedWidget('notfoobar',a=22/7, b='Plimpton 322', c=datetime.now())
awe.update(c=datetime.strptime('20010101','%Y%m%d'))
awe.write_to_file()
```

Is this a recommended (i.e. "best practise") way of implementing the required functionality?

My main question then is:

How can I dynamically create new attributes and iterate through them?

Comment: I mean, does that not work? I don't think there's a best practise for this because it fundamentally goes against what is pythonic. To me it seems that these are not attributes, they are keys, and you should be inheriting from `dict` or `collections.UserDict`. Then, if really necessary, you can overload `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. But why do you even want to do this? Why not just have a base class and a subclass with an extra attribute? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @FHTMitchell I'm not sure why you think this is not Pythonic - perharps I didn't word the question correctly. It's kinda a "poor man's" meta programming I'm trying to do - in that the data is coming from a database (that's why they're attributes/properties). I'm try to write succinct (DRY) code that allows me to use the same base class to do the donkey work of CRUD

Comment: I see, well inherit from dict. That sorts `__init__` out for you. Then do `def __getattr__(self, key): return self[key]`. Quick and easy. You'll have to override `__getattribute__` if you're expecting any fields that conflict with `dict`s. I must say, I'm not entirely convinced this is necessary and having a `self.attributes` `dict` isn't better.